# Troubleshooting A GUI in Tkinter for a Function

Tags: python, math

Consider:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.entryLabel = Label(self, text="Please enter a list of numbers (no commas):")
        self.entryLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.listEntry = Entry(self)
        self.listEntry.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=E)

        self.entryLabel = Label(self, text="Please enter an index value:")
        self.entryLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=E)

        self.indexEntry = Entry(self)
        self.indexEntry.grid(row=1, column=2)

        self.runBttn = Button(self, text="Run Function", command=self.psiFunction)
        self.runBttn.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.answerLabel = Label(self, text="Output List:")
        self.answerLabel.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
```

This code builds a small user interface which is then used for the following function:

```
    def psiFunction(self):
        j = int(self.indexEntry.get())
        valueList = list(self.listEntry.get())
        x = map(int, valueList)
        if x[0] != 0:
            x.insert(0, 0)
        rtn = []
        for n2 in range(0, len(x) * j - 2):
            n = n2 / j
            r = n2 - n * j
            if  r == 0:
                rtn.append(j * x[n])
            else: 
                rtn.append(j * x[n] + r * (x[n + 1] - x[n]))
        self.answer = Label(self, text=rtn)
        self.answer.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

For example if we take j = 3 and our list x = [0,1,2,3,4,5] we get [0,1,2,3.....,13,14,15] as our output list (though the program outputs it as a string).  This is done by calculating values of our output list of length len(x) * j - 2 using terms from the input list for a fixed parameter j.  Now, this example works fine with the above code.  However, if I try to take, say, j=4 x = [0,1,2,3,4,5] nothing comes up - I get no output.  I'm not given any error messages either so I'm not sure why exactly this issue arises.  At first I thought it might have something to do with the list length being smaller than the j value (just taking a wild guess) but this example shows my idea was wrong.  Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Note:  The title refers to the fact that this does not occur when using the function from python, removed from the tkinter code.

EDIT:  Changed code for definition

```
def psiFunction(self):
        j = int(self.indexEntry.get())
        valueList = list(self.listEntry.get())
        x = map(int, valueList)
        length = len(x)
        if x[0] != 0:
            x.insert(0, 0)
        rtn = []
        for n2 in range(0, length * j):
            n = n2 / j
            r = n2 - n * j
            if  r == 0:
                rtn.append(j * x[n])
            else: 
                rtn.append(j * x[n] + r * (x[n + 1] - x[n]))
        self.answer = Label(self, text=rtn)
        self.answer.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why there is no error in your computer but this part of your code do gives an error with `x=[0,1,2,3,4,5]` and `j=4`.

```
for n2 in range(0, len(x) * j - 2):
            n = n2 / j
            r = n2 - n * j
            if  r == 0:
                rtn.append(j * x[n])
            else: 
                rtn.append(j * x[n] + r * (x[n + 1] - x[n]))
```

Let's see, `range(0, len(x) * j - 2)` equals `range(0, 22)`, so when `n2` comes to 21, `n = 5, j = 1`. It will go into the else and there will be `x[6]`, this will throw an indexerror, and you can not get the desired output.

Comment: Well said.  Is there a way to modify this so that this is not an issue?  I think I see at a basic level what the problem is.  Initially when this was made I wanted to only count [1,2,3,4,5] as the length of x.  0 is always present and should never be counted.  I couldn't think of a way to exclude zero from the count though aside from simply subtracting values off of len(x) * j.  If I could, then we would only get 5 x 4 = 20 terms, which would be perfect.  Is there a way to make it count this way that still leaves cases like x = [0,1,2,3,4,5] j = 3 the same?

Comment: It's easy. You can store the `len(x)` to a variable before append 0 to x, such as `length = len(x)` and then use `length * j`. Or use `(len(x)-1) * j`.

Comment: I am not clear. I can only tell the error from your code and some simple solutions. As for logic, I can not help. :(

Comment: I understand the second half of what you described, but wouldn't the first part length = len(x) result in the same thing?  This is probably something simple but I just attempted j=4 and x = [012345] with the changes you described.  I got every term but the 21st term  (i.e. 0,1,2,3....17,18,19).  Now, what I'd like ideally is for the function to treat this as the 20th term (0 is the 0th term 1 is the 1th term 2 is 2nd...) so it would be 4 * x[5] + 0 *(x[n+1] - x[n]) and goes into the 'if' part of the statement.

Comment: I mean use `length=len(x)` right after the `x = map`, before `if x[0] != 0`. So this length will be the length of the list excluding 0.

Comment: Hmm, that does not seem to get me the last term (20) for the case j=4 and x = [012345].  Thank you very much for your help so far by the way.

Comment: Your logic has a -2, you can only get 18 elements in this case. You may have to rethink about it.

Comment: That is true, but it seems the same issue arises when I remove that restriction.  Another case to consider would be j=3 and x = [0,1,2,2,2,3,3] where we get an output of 17 numbers [1.....8,9,9,9], but there should in fact be 3 other 9s appended.  I will repost my updated code for the definition of psi

Comment: 3*6=18, you should only 18 elements. The output is right. Rethink about your logic.

Comment: You are right.  So to be sure I get the other two terms I need to have one extra term in my string.